# 80s Movie about kid gaining super intelligence

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was an 80s movie, the kid had super intelligence, was able to read barcodes and I think could some how ID people if they had arrest records.  I also remember him being attacked by some sort of virus he got through the phone. I want to say it's because of some sort of accident with a computer.

Answer (score 4):

This could be **The Computer Wore Tennis Shoes**. The date isn't right, there is the 1969 version starring Kurt RusselL and the 1995 remake starring Kirk Cameron. An accident involving an electric shock makes him into a human computer. I don't remember details involving reading barcodes or computer virus. But it's a place to start.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good catch. What about *D.A.R.Y.L.* if this isn't right?

Comment: @ToddWilcox why don't you put it up as your own answer then (daryl) and point out why you think it could fit? ;)

Comment: Well D.A.R.Y.L. came to my mind as well, but it doesn't match any of the points (virus/record searching/barcodes/accident)